# can not instantiate driver class in Meteor method

Tags: java, jdbc, meteor

I am trying to use JDBC inside my meteor application but I was not successful in loading the driver class.

the code is simple enough:

```
  console.log("testing jdbc " + process.env.PWD + "/server/ojdbc14-11.2.jar");
  var java = Meteor.require('java');
  java.classpath.push(process.env.PWD + '/server/ojdbc14-11.2.jar');
  console.log("class loaded");
  var driver = java.newInstanceSync('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver');
  console.log("driver instantiated");
  var result = java.callStaticMethodSync('java.sql.DriverManager','registerDriver', driver);
  console.log("driver registered");
  result = java.callStaticMethodSync('java.sql.DriverManager','getConnection', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@local.sertal.ch:7788/KND1');
  console.log("connection established");
```

I am using the [Meteor npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/meteor-npm) package to include `java` the console never shows the message `driver instantiated`

I tried the same thing with a naked nodejs script and it worked fine. The code is almost the same:

```
  var java = require('java');
  java.classpath.push(__dirname + '/ojdbc14-11.2.jar');
  var driver = java.newInstanceSync('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver');
  var result = java.callStaticMethodSync('java.sql.DriverManager','registerDriver', driver);
  var connection = java.callStaticMethodSync('java.sql.DriverManager', 'getConnection', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@local.sertal.ch:7788/KND1');
```

Comment: "Not successful" isn't specific enough. Post the stack trace from the exception. Also note that your log message `class loaded` is misleading; all you've done at that point is add a jar to the places to look for the class.

Comment: thank you for your comment. There is no stack trace as there is no exception. The part java.newInstanceSync is blocking the whole thing. I inspected it with node-inspector and could not step over this line

Comment: Then you need to use a debugger of the appropriate layer. I suspect that you actually are getting a Java exception that the Javascript wrapper isn't correctly passing up. Please also post the "naked Node.js" script that you say is working.